# Number into alphabetic sequence

Tags: javascript

So I have a situation in which I will be given a number (between 1 - 1000) and will need to convert it into a string as follows:

```
1  = A
2  = B
3  = C
...
25 = Y
26 = Z
27 = AA
28 = AB
...
52 = AZ
53 = BA
54 = BB
55 = BC
...
78 = BZ
79 = CA
80 = CB
...
702 = ZZ
703 = AAA
```

So far I have this, but I'm getting the wrong answers:

```
count_to_string = function(count) {
    var div = Math.floor(count/26);
    var rem = count % 26; 
    ll = '';
    if (div > 0) ll = ll + String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + (div-1));
    return ll + String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + (rem-1));
};
```

running it with input of 26 gives output: A@

Comment: post some bad output

Comment: running it with input of 26 gives output: A@

Comment: you're back a char one too many. Try omitting the subtraction

Comment: six is actually zero here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return  only the string, you can use loops while increasing string concatenated. This method does not have a limit:

```js
function countToString(count){
  var arr = [];
  while(count >> 0 > 0){
    arr.unshift(String.fromCharCode(65 + --count % 26));
    count /= 26
  }
  return arr.join("")
}

[1,2,3,25,26,27,28,52,53,54,55,78,79,80,702,703,99999,6e6].forEach(function(num){
  document.write(num + " = " + countToString(num) + "<br>")
})
```

Comment: @JonCrowell I put another method that could get values greater than 702

Comment: @JonCrowell I saw a notification of vote and came up me a new solution, you can see now, it is simpler and faster. Excuse my English.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this would help you out instead of Math.floor, because floor rounds the answer and truncate will just leave you with what you want

```
    var div = Math.trunc(count/26);
```

Comment: `Math.floor(27/26)`  = 1 and also `Math.floor(51/26)` = 1.

Comment: @Jon Crowell you're right, so floor always rounds down to the lower number. I saw this example [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and assumed that they functioned different, but for wZVanG's issue they do function the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `rem-1` instead a `rem`. Here is your code with the fix and an output:

```
var count_to_string = function(count) {
var div = Math.floor(count/26);
var rem = count % 26;

  ll = '';
  if (div > 0) ll = ll + String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + (div-1));
  return ll + String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + (rem)); //Here is the fix
};

for (var i = 0; i < 58; i++) {
  console.log(count_to_string(i));
}
```

And the output is:

```
A
B
C
D
E
...
V
W
X
Y
Z
AA
AB
AC
...
AZ
BA
BB
BC
BD
BE
BF
```

Comment: You are welcome. And what will be your expected output after `ZZ`? Maybe I can help with that.

Comment: I guess it would be `AAA` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One first suggestion is that you compute the remainder first and then subtract it of the number before computing the quocient. Doing so the division will always be exact and you'll get no errors due to rounding. In other words, change the first two lines of your function to be like this:

```
var rem = count % 26; 
var div = Math.floor((count-rem)/26);
```

I think this may help a lot in avoiding errors, but I'll try to think of something else and then edit this answer.